# RubyMotion require support

Tags: rubygems, bundler, rubymotion

Is there any way to use Ruby `require` inside RubyMotion to require classes and modules from Ruby `stdlib`?

I found two gems for that:

- [motion-require](https://github.com/clayallsopp/motion-require) but it is for requiring relative files inside project
- [motion-bundler](https://github.com/archan937/motion-bundler) but it crashes as described in [issue](https://github.com/archan937/motion-bundler/issues/14)

Has anyone found solution already?

Answer (score 0):

RubyMotion does not have the MRI stdlib available.
You should find motion specific gems as a replacement, or a specific pod.

Comment: I mean requires like `Forwardable`, `Singleton`, `SecureRandom`, `Base64`, `CGI` and so on. Any support for them?

Comment: No, not at this point. You will have to use gems or pods that implement these.

Comment: Squixy did you ever find a solution? Am also trying Singleton and Forwardable, but feel I'll be writing it the old way.